# Images within modal box

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, modal-dialog

I am looking to put images within a modal box. 
I can load the modal box with an image in it but every time i press next image, the modal box disappears. I am at my wits end with this.

I do not want to use any form of JavaScript. I want to stick to pure HTML and CSS.

What am i doing wrong

My code is here
http://codepen.io/kinivrus/pen/XmJvRJ?editors=110

regards
David

```
<a href="#portfolio"><img src="portfolio.gif" width="591" height="591"         alt="Portfolio" /></a>
<div id="portfolio" class="portfolioModal">
  <div>
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

<h2>Portfolio</h2>

<div class="slider">
  <ul class="frames">
    <li id="one" class="slide">
      <img src="8k3N3EL (1).jpg" width="640" height="320" alt="slide 1" />
      <nav>
        <a class="prev" href="#five">&larr;</a>
        <a class="next" href="#two">&rarr;</a>
      </nav>
    </li>

    <li id="two" class="slide">
      <img src="blue-bar-1255161.jpg" width="640" height="320" alt="slide 2" />
      <nav>
        <a class="prev" href="#one">&larr;</a>
        <a class="next" href="#three">&rarr;</a>
      </nav>
    </li>

    <li id="three" class="slide">
      <img src="download (1).jpg" width="640" height="320" alt="" />
      <nav>
        <a class="prev" href="#two">&larr;</a>
        <a class="next" href="#four">&rarr;</a>
      </nav>
    </li>
    <li id="four" class="slide">
      <img src="download.jpg" width="640" height="320" alt="" />
      <nav>
        <a class="prev" href="#three">&larr;</a>
        <a class="next" href="#five">&rarr;</a>
      </nav>
    </li>

    <li id="five" class="slide">
      <img src="startup-594091.jpg" width="640" height="320" alt="" />
      <nav>
        <a class="prev" href="#four">&larr;</a>
        <a class="next" href="#one">&rarr;</a>
      </nav>
    </li>
    </ul>

   </div>
```

Comment: I am not good at pure css but in your case, and according to my knowledge, the url # sign serves as an hash tag instead of an id selector. So once clicked the page tries to load and location the name tagged and the modal effect disappear.

I have always been using a combination of both js and css for modal.

Comment: If you can give up the onClick navigation and choose autoplay, then this may give you some idea

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do these changes with only CSS is to use radio buttons, with the `:checked` pseudo-selector. This will not hide your modal.

Here is a pen showcasing it the method: http://codepen.io/_Billy_Brown/pen/VjxZzx?editors=1100

This method does not easily allow looping with arrow buttons, but it does with a list of radio buttons. Using the `~`, you can select a sibling element, but that only works down the document, not backward up it.

The following:

```
.images {
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}

[class*="slide-"] {
  opacity: 0.0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.5s;
}

.to-one:checked ~ .images .slide-one,
.to-two:checked ~ .images .slide-two,
.to-three:checked ~ .images .slide-three {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

relies on a structure similar to this:

```
<div class="modal">
  <input type="radio" name="image-slider" class="to-one" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="image-slider" class="to-two">
  <input type="radio" name="image-slider" class="to-three">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="image-1.png" class="slide-one">
    <img src="image-2.png" class="slide-two">
    <img src="image-3.png" class="slide-three">
  </div>
</div>
```

I used `opacity` to fade the images in and out, but you could use `display: none;` to make the invisible ones actually disappear, or even better, use FlexBox's `order` property to rearrange them when the radio buttons are clicked.